# If my question on Metabase has an image column with image previews in it, is it possible to export it to excel as an image type column itself?

Tags: excel, metabase

I have a question on Metabase that has a column of image type i.e. it has image previews in it. I want to export that question to Metabase but want to see the image previews in Excel as well. Is that possible?

Currently when I export it to Excel, I get the url links for the images but no previews. Is there a way to get the image previews in Excel automatically?